# How to toggle display of inline/block elements without losing original display

Tags: javascript, html, css

A common way to show/hide elements is to toggle `display` between `none` and `block`. However, some elements like `<a>` or `<span>` should not be toggled back to `block` but rather `inline`. Is there a neat way to toggle visibility without losing the original display property?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial?

Comment: Since I have the following style.css: `[lang] {display: none;}` to hide all elements initially - setting `display: initial` does not work, neither does `display: revert`. Even if I remove that from style.css (which displays all languages initially) - setting `display: initial` does not show the hidden element.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of toggling between `display: none` and `display: block` you could just toggle `display: none`.

For example:

```js
$(function(){

  $("button").on("click", function(){
    $("a").toggleClass("hidden");
  });

});
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">Link</a>

<button>Toggle link visiblity</button>
```

Comment: Note that you do not need jQuery for this necessarily. The JavaScript offers pure versions of this as well: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp